# Projection on a linear subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, numerical-linear-algebra

Let $U = span\{u_1, \, u_2, \, \cdots, \, u_p\}$ and $V = span\{v_1, \, v_2, \, \cdots, \, v_q\}$ denote two linear vector subspaces of an $m$-dimensional linear vector space $W$ such that $W = U \oplus V$, $n = p+q > m$, $U \not\subset V$,
$V \not\subset U$, and $U \cap V \neq \emptyset$.

How to determine an orthogonal projector to the subspaces defined as 
$U \cap V$, $W \ominus U$?

Comment: How to determine, indeed?

Comment: @Math1000: Sorry?

Comment: If $E$ is a (real or complex) finite-dimensional vector space equipped with an inner product $\left\langle \cdot,\cdot \right\rangle$ and $V \subset E$ a linear subspace of $E$, consider $(e_{1},\ldots,e_{p})$ an *orthonormal basis* of $V$. Then, for all $x \in E$, the orthogonal projection on $V$ is defined by :

$$ \Pi_{V}(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{p} \left\langle x,e_{i} \right\rangle e_{i}. $$

Comment: @jibounet: How to deetermine it for $U \cap V$, $W \ominus U$? being given that $U$ and $V$ are not defined in terms of orthonormal basis.

Comment: @GamalELGHAZALY : I would consider a basis of these linear subspaces, transform in into an orthonormal basis (using, for example, the Gram-Schmidt algorithm or QR decomposition) and use this orthonormal basis for with the formula above.

Comment: @GamalELGHAZALY That is the thought I have when reading your post (like if I read the problem in a textbook). Have you made no effort to solve this problem?

Comment: @Math1000, I am not math guy. I did find a solution here in this paper. http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0898122198002429

Comment: @jibounet: Thanks